# Creating a Responsive Tic Tac Toe Field Layout in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, responsive-design, tic-tac-toe

I'm currently working on implementing a responsive Tic Tac Toe field in Flutter, and I've encountered a layout issue. I've managed to display the "cross" and "circle" symbols, but the challenge lies in the layout of the Tic Tac Toe field itself.

```
Column(children: Expanded(Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(48, 44, 48, 14),
  color: TTColorTheme.onBackground,
  child: GridView.count(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    crossAxisCount: 3,
    mainAxisSpacing: 8,
    crossAxisSpacing: 8,
    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    children: List.generate(9, (index) {
      int row = index ~/ 3;
      int col = index % 3;
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          color: TTColorTheme.background,
          child: null,
        ),
      );
    }),
  ),
),]); //...
```

To not confuse anybody everytime I talk about the Container I mean the parent container with the onBackground color.

The problem arises from the fact that the field is positioned within a Column widget, causing the Container to expand to take up as much space as possible. To work around this, I had to adjust the margin in a somewhat weird way to ensure that only the area where the main/cross axis spacing is defined the container's color is being shown.

This approach is not really responsive, and I've attempted several solutions, including using a Stack, IntrinsicHeight (along with a fixed height for the container), but they didn't yield the desired results. In each attempt, a small portion of the container's color remained visible on the edges, and I also had to warkaround there with the margin, so that it looked normal.

I'm looking for advice on how to create a responsive layout for the Tic Tac Toe field to ensure it displays correctly on various screen sizes and orientations.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking out ResponsiveWrapper -> [responsive_framework](https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_framework)

```
 return MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, widget) => ResponsiveWrapper.builder(
        ClampingScrollWrapper.builder(context, widget!),
        maxWidth: 1200,
        minWidth: 480,
        defaultScale: true,
        breakpoints: [
          ResponsiveBreakpoint.resize(480, name: MOBILE),
          ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(800, name: TABLET),
          ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(1000, name: DESKTOP),
        ],
      ),
      home: Scaffold(...
```

Comment: Made my own tic tac toe in Flutter, perfectly working. Watch this tutorial I made, the code for the game is on github, link in the description. Video -
https://youtu.be/Md9kg8HANMQ